# Cross-site request forgery token viewable in source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

Should my Cross-site request forgery TOKEN be viewable on my web page source code 
I am running a rails app in production and can see Cross-site request forgery  token i am guess it should NOT be viewable

Comment: It must be "visible" and it must be unique per session. Once the visitor sends a request the csrf token is sent to the server too and is compared against the token stored in the session.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to put it on the web page without it being viewable.  If you can't put it on the web page then you can't use it.  There's no "secret" part of the web page which isn't in the source, or headers, both of which can easily be viewed.  So, logically, if it is to have any function whatsoever, it must be viewable.

In order for it to function as part of a security system, therefore, the security of the system must NOT rely on nobody being able to see what the token is, and that is indeed the case.  The security of the system depends on the token matching a stored value server-side: in other words, it means that the token provided with the form, ie sent from the server to the client, needs to match the one submitted BACK TO THE SERVER by the form.

Read this:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: What if the attacker copies the token in my form's hidden field and uses it to submit the form from his evil site? That way the form request contains the legitimate token as the one with a logged-in user's form. Note: Assuming the evil user is using the same PC which a logged-in user has used few minutes ago.

Comment: Isn't that like saying "what if someone leaves themselves logged into a website then someone else comes along and pretends to be them"?  I don't know how anyone could defend against that.

Comment: Agree, I am talking about the scenario of a logged-in user who forgets to lock his system, and that opens up vulnerability for hackers around him. In that case, a CSRF token is not required for the hacker though ;)

Comment: @shasikanth web security doesn't (and possible can't) protect against people leaving themselves logged in and leaving while a bad actor is **physically** near by, waiting to jump into their seat.  That's not the problem they're trying to solve - the user is expected to deal with that.